# Воздействие append на вид страницы

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, почему при **append** результат отличается от статического html?

Я накидал пример для иллюстрации: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLSELJ1WJACU

```js
$("#test_jq").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");
$("#test_jq").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");
$("#test_jq").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");


$("#test_jq2").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");
$("#test_jq2").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");
$("#test_jq2").append("<div class=\"test\"></div>");
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>

<h2>Test preview</h2>

<div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>

<div id="test_jq"></div>

<h2>Test preview 2</h2>

<div id="test_jq2"></div>

<div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно занимательный пример. Когда вы ложите в статическую верстку чистые `inline-block` - с табуляцией(или пробелами, не важно) и переносами строк - вы потом увидите эти самые пробелы и переносы строк. Попробуйте добавить такое `css` правило:

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Просто когда вы делаете `elem.append(childElem)` - вы не добавляете переносов и пробелов, и всё отрабатывает как, по идее, и хочется.

Comment: Спасибо! Сразу не сообразил...

Comment: @mat.twg Если мой ответ вам помог - приймите его.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
<h2>Test preview</h2>

<div><div class="test"></div><div class="test"></div><div class="test"></div></div>

<div id="test_jq"></div>
```

По-моему, все ясно.

Comment: Спасибо! Не понимаю почему Вас минусанули, действительно - всё ясно!

Comment: @mat.twg Я тоже не понимаю. У каждого здесь свое мнение. Всё вместе это называется сообщество ruSO :).